# Why I am not able to replace the NSMutableString value in foundCharacters method of NSXMLParser in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsxmlparser

I am new in iOS and I am facing the problem regarding to replace the string value in `foundCharacters` method of **NSXMLPerser**.

My code is like this

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{  
    myMutableStringassignedObj=[[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:string];
    NSLog(@"Array String: %@",myMutableStringassignedObj);
    myMutableStringassignedObj = [[myMutableStringassignedObj stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&"
                                         withString:@"and"] mutableCopy];//I am changing string like this but it not working
    NSData *data = [myMutableStringassignedObj dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    responseassigneddict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
    NSLog(@"JSON DATA = %@",responseassigneddict);
}
```

Due to the **&** It's give me null value. Is there is any way to change it. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: not clear what you exactly want!

Comment: @Lion I need to replace the content of string.

Comment: @Lion Yes  that is.

Comment: please give content of string and what you want from that sring.

Comment: @NarendraPandey  String Content is : Staircase no 3,4,1  lobby area of B & C,passage area and unit no -1502 till 1504 there is no light reliance lift passage area no light.

Comment: I tried using the method `[[myMutableStringassignedObj stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"and"] mutableCopy]`. It didn't work for me. So, I tried other method for doing the same. You can check my answer for that

Comment: Hi, you are not getting `NULL` due to `&` in `NSString`. Please check my answer for clear understanding of your problem :). Feel free to comment for any doubt

Comment: is your problem resolved?

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanyaAmjuri No

Answer (score 2):

Replace your string modification method with this

```
[myMutableStringassignedObj replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"and" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, myMutableStringassignedObj.length)];
```

After that, place your string in an NSArray or NSDictionary.

```
NSArray *array = @[myMutableStringassignedObj];
```

The problem here is: You are not decoding `jsonData` from `NSData` object. `jsonData` should always start with `Array` or `Dictionary`. Here, you converted `NSString` into `NSData` and trying to decode that using `NSJSONSerialization`. So, you are getting an error due to that. I checked the error code.

So, to decode the `NSData` into a `jsonObject/Foundation Object`, you are supposed to place your String into an `NSArray` or `NSDictionary` and then convert it in to `NSData` using `NSJSONSerialization`

```
NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:array options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
NSError *error;
id responseassigneddict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
NSLog(@"JSON DATA = %@",responseassigneddict);
```

**Edit:**

As discussed in comments, please use an [XMLParser](https://github.com/simhanature/SHXMLParser) library to solve this.

Comment: Nothing Happen.

Comment: I figured out your problem

Comment: Please tell me.

Comment: Please check my answer

Comment: @muju it's encoding issue. Try my solution once . Hope it will work.

Comment: @KrishnaCA I have used your code but it give me error "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Series."

Comment: @Muju, show me your string once. Atleast, the format your string is in.

Comment: @KrishnaCA Please see the Image that is my string and after "Staff has left.  F" I am getting & that's why it get crash.

Comment: @Muju Try pasting your Json string in http://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer and check whether the json is valid or not once

Comment: @KrishnaCA I am using XMLParser. How to see it in JSON Viewer.

Comment: @KrishnaCA Please see the Image now.

Comment: @Muju, The string you are getting. Not the xml data. Print the NSString in your console and paste it in jsonviewer once.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129195/discussion-between-krishnaca-and-muju).

Comment: @KrishnaCA Thanks for your help by using xmlconverter in I am able to done this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it something like,

```
  NSString *string = @"hello & hello";

 NSString *result = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"and"];

NSLog(@"result : %@",result);
```

there is no meed of convert it to `mutable string`!

Comment: I am using Mutable String that why I need to convert it.

Comment: Can you please answer my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43539307/how-to-post-string-with-special-character-and-thai-language-using-xml-parsing-in

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSMutableString *String = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@"B&c"];

    [String replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"and" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, String.length)];
    NSLog(@"string after replacing %@",String);
```

Output:

```
string after replacing `Bandc`
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a issue of encoding the data which is having special character. Use below line code directly instead of replacing & or any Special character.

```
NSCharacterSet *set = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"];

NSString *encodedData = [myMutableStringassignedObj stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:set]];

NSData *data = [encodedData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: I declare NSCharacterSet *set; in .h file and then write your code from NSString.

Comment: use this NSCharacterSet *set = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"]; and remove the NSCharacterSet object you declared.

Comment: Now it give me Null value

Comment: first convert it into data and take it in dictionary  .                                                                                                        NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:myMutableStringassignedObj] options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
    NSError *error;
    id responseassigneddict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
    NSLog(@"JSON DATA = %@",responseassigneddict);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128039/discussion-between-rubiya-faniband-and-muju).